# Regex that matches everything before some square brackets and after

Tags: regex

I want to create an expression that captures everything before and after some square brackets.

Such that:

```
Test - ho-server-01[IWM]/Memory Usage
```

Would capture:

```
Test - ho-server-01
Memory Usage
```

A few more examples:

```
Test - ho-server-01[IWM]/Memory Usage
IMWS Test - ho-server-01 [IWM]/Memory Usage
```

So far i have this `([^[]*)`

Comment: If there is just a single pair `^(.+?)\[[^][]*]/(.+)` https://regex101.com/r/QD1eNC/1

Comment: Thanks again my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```php
(.*)\[[^\]\[]*\](.*)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/mwkrne/2).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\]\[]*                 any character except: '\]', '\[' (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \]                       ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```regex
^([^[]+)\[[^]]+\](.*)$
```

See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/dtvekU/1

Comment: If there are no brackets before the 2 opening and closing, this is a more efficient pattern. +1